# ValueError: Unable to create tensor, you should probably activate padding with 'padding=True' to batched tensors with same length

Tags: python, speech-recognition, tensor, huggingface-transformers, torch

I am working on fine tuning the wav2vec2 XLSR on kannada language with my own datasets and i keep running into this error, even though i have set the padding = True, it keeps throwing the error.

update:

```
import torch
import torchaudio
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import Wav2Vec2ForCTC, Wav2Vec2Processor
```

## Load the test dataset

```
test_dataset = dataset['test']

processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("/content/container_0        /ckpts/checkpoint-1000")
model = Wav2Vec2ForCTC.from_pretrained("/content/container_0/ckpts/checkpoint-1000")

resampler = torchaudio.transforms.Resample(48000, 16_000)
```

## Preprocessing the datasets.

## We need to read the audio files as arrays

```
def speech_file_to_array_fn(batch):
speech_array, sampling_rate = torchaudio.load(batch["path"])
batch["speech"] = resampler(speech_array).squeeze().numpy()
return batch
```

test_dataset = test_dataset.map(speech_file_to_array_fn)
max_length = 50

def prepare_inputs(batch):
input_values = processor(batch["speech"], sampling_rate=16_000,  return_tensors="pt", padding=True).input_values
# Pad the inputs to the maximum length
input_values = torch.nn.functional.pad(input_values, (0, max_length - input_values.shape[-1]), value=0)
attention_mask = torch.ones(input_values.shape)
return {"input_values": input_values[0][:max_length], "attention_mask": attention_mask[0][:max_length]}

```
def prepare_inputs(batch):
input_values = processor(batch["speech"], sampling_rate=16_000, return_tensors="pt", padding=True).input_values
# Pad the inputs to the maximum length
input_values = torch.nn.functional.pad(input_values, (0, max_length - input_values.shape[-1]), value=0)
attention_mask = torch.ones(input_values.shape)
return {"input_values": input_values[0], "attention_mask":  attention_mask[0]}


inputs = test_dataset.map(prepare_inputs, batched=True,   batch_size=len(test_dataset))

with torch.no_grad():
logits = model(inputs["input_values"],      attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"]).logits

predicted_ids = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)

print("Prediction:", processor.batch_decode(predicted_ids))
print("Reference:", test_dataset["text"][:2])
```

Special tokens have been added in the vocabulary, make sure the associated word embeddings are fine-tuned or trained.

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

in <cell line: 42>()
41
42 with torch.no_grad():
---> 43     logits = model(inputs["input_values"], attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"]).logits
44
45 predicted_ids = torch.argmax(logits, dim=-1)

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/transformers/models/wav2vec2/modeling_wav2vec2.py in forward(self, input_values)
431
432     def forward(self, input_values):
--> 433         hidden_states = input_values[:, None]
434
435         # make sure hidden_states require grad for gradient_checkpointing

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

the error is at the line '''
logits = model(inputs["input_values"], attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"]).logits '''

Comment: Is that dataset publicly available or could you provide a reproducible example with a publicly available dataset?

Comment: I have made my own datasets and used it.
should i try with a publicly available datasets and try to reproduce the error?

Comment: A public dataset would help people like me to reproduce the error and provide an answer. So yes, please.

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply but i have used a public dataset and now i am getting a different error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you are running. Keep in mind that I can't see your screen.